Find and Replace all the values using regex in android studio with different dimention values
How to replace all the different values with matching format using prefex or suffix from whole project in android studio?
like I wants to search static values define in xml with ssp or sdp and replace it from dimen resources
I can find all the values using (\d+)ssp or (\d+)sdp using find window with .* but how I can replaceall with @dimen/_10ssp ?
here @dimen/_ is prefix 10 is any value and ssp is sufix

I have found regex which may help
Using (\d+)ssp or (\d+)sdp you can find all the matching values and for replace it with suffix or prefix you can use @dimen/_$1ssp or @dimen/_$1sdp


Please always provide code as (formatted) text, not as images to make it more discoverable.

@tyg image code is just for explanation... if I will provide code there is no use of it so... !!!
